# How to use GET on an external URL

Tags: php, api, get

I am using an API that returns JSON from a `GET` request

Eg.

```
https://api.domain.com/v1/Account/{auth_id}/Call/{call_uuid}
```

Returns

```
 {
    "call_duration": 4,
    "total_amount": "0.00400"
  }
```

How can I call this page from within a script and save `call_duation` and `total_amount` as separate variables?

Something like the following?:

```
$call_duration =
$_GET[https://api.domain.com/v1/Account/{auth_id}/Call/{call_uuid}, 'call_duration'];
```

Comment: That looks a lot like JSON, [which PHP can handle](http://us1.php.net/json).

Comment: that doesn't answer his question though, which was "how do I make the request to the other server"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_GET[]` contains the `get` parameters that are passed to your code - they don't generate a `GET` request.

You could use [`curl`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php) to make your request:

```
    $ch = curl_init("https://api.domain.com/v1/Account/{auth_id}/Call/{call_uuid}");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);       
    curl_close($ch);
    $result = json_decode($output);
```

Comment: thanks, so to select `call_duration` would be `$result['call_duration']`?

Comment: Exactly. Try it and see.

Answer (score 2):

If PHP has allow_url_fopen enabled you can simply do

```
json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.domain.com/v1/Account/{auth_id}/Call/{call_uuid}'))
```

Otherwise you'll have to resort to using something like Curl to get the request going. $_GET is a superglobal array which doesn't actually *do* anything. It only contains what the script was *started* with. It does not make any requests itself.

Comment: Yes - either file_get_contents or curl will do this.

Comment: As I said, depends on the PHP config ;)

Comment: Good thing that OP gets the choice now... one of these two examples ought to work on most servers, I think.

Comment: It sure should. I don't think there are any other ways to initiate an outside connection from within PHP (that is, if curl is disabled and allow_url_fopen is disallowed as well)

Answer (score -1):

Use curl to get the JSON, then json_decode to decode it into PHP variables

```
$auth_id = 'your auth id here';
$call_uuid = 'your call_uuid here';

// initialise curl, set URL and options
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.domain.com/v1/Account/{$auth_id}/Call/{$call_uuid}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// get the response and decode it
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response = json_decode($response);

$call_duration = $response['call_duration'];
$total_amount = $response['total_amount'];
```